# Joomla: localizing user registration, activation email & messages 

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to know please, where to localize the messages that are displayed when registering new user ??

for ex" Joomla User successfully registered."

or "Your Account has been successfully activated. You can now log in using the username and password you chose during the registration."

Can I translate them with JoomFish ?? Where can I find them ??

Also, where can I translate the activation email sent to new users ??

Thanks,
HopeWise

Answer (score 1):

These messages comes from Language Files, These are stored here Joomla Location / Languages // en-GB. // en-GB.com_user.ini

Please searcg REG_ACTIVATE_COMPLETE_TITLE

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: But, why its not shown when I view the website in Arabic ? although there are a translation for them in the arabic language file ?

Comment: Did your template support RTL languages ??? If you have arabic translation, it should show, are you using any other component for registration e.g. Community Builder or JomSOcial